# Nexus S: slow, jerky web browser scrolling in ICS (compared to Gingerbread)

Tags: performance, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bugs, stock-browser

My Nexus S was OTA-upgraded yesterday to Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3 from 2.3 (Gingerbread), and I'm still finding my way around.  One problem I've noticed has been web browser performance, particularly scrolling.

When I load [Google News](http://news.google.com/) and scroll it up and down with my finger, or when I swipe fast enough that it has enough momentum to continue scrolling for a while, scrolling is very jerky instead of smooth like Gingerbread was.

Is this a known problem, and if so is there a fix planned or a workaround I can use?  This sounds like a trivial display problem but it actually makes the browser difficult to use for reading and scanning pages.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google News on my Galaxy Nexus is smooth like butter, no matter what speed I scrolled at. It might be that the Nexus S processor is a little underpowered for the new browser. Have you tried any other browsers?